# Concept: Is mongo right for applying schemas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, globalization, concept, database-relations

I am currently in charge of checking wether it is valuable for one of our upcoming products to be developed on mongo.

Without going too much into detail, I'll try to explain, what the app does.

The app simply has "entities". These entities are technical stuff, like cell phones, TVs, Laptops, tablet pcs, and so forth.

Of course, a cell phone has other attributes than a Tablet PCs and a Laptop has even other attributes, like RAM, CPU, display size and so on.

Now I want to have something that we wanna call a scheme: We define that we need to have saved the display size, amount of ram size of flash devices, processor type, processor speed and so on for tablet pcs. For cell phone we might save display size, GSM, Edge, 3g, 4g, processor, ram, touch screen technology, bla bla bla. I think you got it :)

What I want to realize is, that each "category" has a schema and when one of the system's users enters a new product (let's say the new iphone 4), the app constructs the form to be filled out with the appropriate attributes.

So far it sounds nice and should not be a problem with mongo. But now the tough for which I could not find a clean solution....

An attribute modeled in mongo looks like:

```
{
_id: 1234456, name: "Attribute name", type: 0, "description"
}
```

But what to do, if i need this attribute in several languages, like:

```
{
en: {name: "Attribute name", type: 0, "description"},
de: {name: "Name des Attributs, type: 0, "Beschreibung"}
}
```

I also need to ensure that the german attribute gets updated as soon as the english gets updated, for instance when type changes from 0 to 1.

Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

A document in a mongo database can have any or all of its attributes updated in one `update` statement. There are no triggers -- if you want the document to be updated when the type attribute changes, you'll need to do that in application logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in a number of different ways.

You can have an array of language translations embedded in an attribute document:

```
{
    _id: 1234, 
    type: 0,
    somethingElse : "foobar",
    translation: [
        "en" : { name: "Attribute name", description : "Description" }
        "de" : { name: "Name des Attributs", description: "Beschreibung" }
    ]
}
```

Or you can separate translations into a separate collection where you can store translation key and translations for all languages for that key.

Or you can also use your model and update multiple attributes with one update.

It all depends on your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB, the task of ensuring a logical relationship within a document or between documents (e.g. every description must appear in these five languages) is the responsibility of the client program.  There are queries that could be made to find documents that meet or do not meet your specifications, but the database itself will not prevent you from storing documents that do not meet your specifications (except for special cases like unique indices).

The advantage that MongoDB would have over a relational database is in the ability to expand your schema over time as your needs change.  From a performance standpoint, the ability to push updates to the database without round-tripping the entire document (using $set or $push or another update feature) could be helpful, and the ability to flexibly index on various compound fields could make queries fast.

If I understand your use case, the total amount of data will be relatively small (a few thousands of documents, each no more than a few KB) and so will fit in RAM on a modest system and so be fast.  But you'll be writing client-side logic to impose the structure and relationships you want.